# Postgresql: How to concat table by row?

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, union

Let's say I have two table.

```
FIRST_TAB
ID  NAME
===========
1   a
2   b
```

and

```
SECOND_TAB
ID  NAME
===========
3   c
4   d
```

Is there any way to make view/new table so that I could do a query like this ? (My real data has around 23 tables, no duplicate, all of them has the same column).

```
SELECT * FROM NEWVIEW;
ID NAME  OPTIONAL
==================
1  a     FIRST_TAB
2  b     FIRST_TAB
3  c     SECOND_TAB
4  d     SECOND_TAB
```

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW newview AS
  SELECT a.id,
         a.name,
         'FIRST_TAB' AS optional
    FROM FIRST_TAB a
  UNION ALL
  SELECT b.id,
         b.name,
         'SECOND_TAB' AS optional
    FROM FIRST_TAB b
```

The optional column is a static string where you can specify what you need, assuming no special characters.

`UNION ALL` is faster than using `UNION`, because it doesn't remove duplicates.  If you need to remove duplicates, just remove the "ALL" keyword (I believe the `optional` column value will be taken from the earliest of the unioned statements where the duplicates appears).

Reference:

- [CREATE VIEW](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-createview.html)

Comment: ah thanks, I skim through it but somehow miss it. Is wildcard available here? I have a lot of column.

Comment: @Tg: You can, but it's not recommended because UNION'ed statements need to match data types at each ordinal position in the result set.  IE: id being INT, the first column on every subsequent UNION'd query must be an INT.  If column order every changes, you're in for trouble.